# Limit depth of .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

For various reasons, I have the entry in my `.gitignore` in the root of a project:

```
 *.c
```

As I desire, this ignores all C files from being included. However, I really only want the C files to only be ignored in the root directory, and not all the sub-directories:

```
 foo.c
 bar.c
 folder/baz.c
```

In the above scheme, I only want foo.c and bar.c ignored. I do not want this gitignore rule to work recursively. How do I do this?

I'm aware of being able to negate the rule with `!*.c`, but I'd rather not do that for every subdirectory. (This is what I am currently doing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
/*.c
```

I was looking for a bit from the manpage to quote, and found that this exact example's in there! Oops!

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, `"/*.c"` matches `"cat-file.c"` but not `"mozilla-sha1/sha1.c"`.