# How do I tell git to ignore files that start with a tilde?

Tags: git, gitignore

My text editor creates swap files that start with a tilde.  I accidentally checked on of these into git.  How do I tell git to ignore any files like this anywhere in my project tree?

So I had

```
/folder/another/file.txt
/folder/another/~file.txt
```

I want `~file.txt` to be ignored by git.

Comment: Did you try the obvious? Add `~*` to .gitignore.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use a .gitignore file:

```
echo '~*' >> .gitignore
```

Alternatively, you can also write this line to `.git/info/exclude` which is a project-wide local ignore file (which you obviously cannot check in, as you can do with `.gitignore`).

Comment: That seems to work.  I thought that the .gitignore file only applied for the root directory.   But this does seem to cause such files anywhere in my file tree to be ignored.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: It applies to the directory it sits in (and any of the directories therein). So `/folder/a/.gitignore` would have no influence on anything below `/folder/b/` but it would affect `/folder/a/sub/file.txt`.

Comment: So based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551569/limit-depth-of-gitignore it looks like I have to add a slash to the front of my other rules because I want them to only apply to top level directory and not recursively.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Yes, I didn't get that from your OP.

Comment: No, I hadn't realized that this was the way gitignore works until I got your answer.  I'm pretty sure this is different from cvsignore and  the way that subversion ignores work.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '~*' >> .gitignore
```

This will append the needed entry.

Else edit the `.gitignore` file manually and add `~*` on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

1. first check if git ever added your file to the tracked files.

   git status

yes ? so remove the file or folder from git

```
git rm --cached <file-name> or git rm -r --cached <folder-name>
```

then, append to the .gitignore file the followed pattern (an asterisk "*" matches anything except a slash.)

```
echo '.~*' >> .gitignore
```

that's all folks !